# + selector ("sibling") in sass

Tags: css, sass

From here - http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp -

> element+element
>
> div + p
>
> Selects all `p` elements that are placed immediately after `div` elements

for example  -

```
div+p {
   ...
}
```

How could I select the same in sass using the `p` as nested in `div` (or any other concept) ?

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/etn4ebcd/)

Comment: Did you look at [this previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15246387/css-and-or-sass-sibling-selector-upwards)?

Comment: @URL87 The `element+element` selector is used to select elements that is placed immediately after (not inside) the first specified element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In SASS

```
div {

   + p {
    /* paragraph styles here */
   }
}
```

or just

```
div + p
```

Useful standard CSS selectors article - [**HERE**](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048)

Comment: I want "immediately after" selector , not "inner" selector  .

Comment: Note that `+` and `>` are not the same selectors (!).

Comment: @Paulie_D : You did not understand me ... I'll clarify my post again